# Laptop sleep: How to go into S3 easily?

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, suspend, acpi

Laptop: Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo Pi-3525
OS: Vista

When my laptop is plugged in and I close the lid, it goes into S1 sleep. This means that there is still:

- fan noise (annoying when trying to sleep at night)
- lots of power consumed (so if I then unplug the laptop and toss it in the bag, by the time I'm at school it's already drained and beeping ominously).

What I want is S3 sleep, it solves both problems.

I've found a roundabout way to go into S3 sleep:

- Unplug laptop
- Close lid (or click Sleep in Start menu)
- Plug laptop back in if needed

**The question:** How do I force Windows to use always use S3 sleep when I close the lid?

One thing I've tried is: `dumppo admin minsleep=s3` (dumppo from [here](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Products/Oemtest/v1.1/WOSTest/Tools/Acpi/dumppo.exe))
Afterwards running just `dumppo admin` confirms that minsleep has been set, but closing the lid still goes into S1. Also, after a reboot, minsleep is reset to s1. I think dumppo is incompatible with Vista... *MCE Standby Tool* was recommended as a Vista-compatible alternative to dumppo, but it doesn't have any effect either.

I looked in the BIOS settings, but there are no settings relating to ACPI sleeps/suspends there.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've checked your BIOS already but double check again to be sure, keywords to look for are "S3", "Sleep", "Wakeup", and "Resume" in the Power Management option.

The only other thing I can think about is it might not go into S3 if you have a mouse or even a usb keyboard connected to it. I know you haven't specified in your question whether you did or didn't have a usb device plugged in but anyways you can read this [microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841858) for a registry hack.

In short you'll just need to enter this registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\usb
"USBBIOSx"=DWORD:00000000
```

Comment: sorry I just noticed how old this question was...

Answer (score -1):

... Hibernate?

Control Panel--> Power Options--> In the second or third tab, it will ask you what you what you want to do when you close the lid of the laptop, press the power button, or press the sleep button. Select "Hibernation (You have to first enable hibernation on the 3rd/4th tab.) under "close the lid of the laptop.".

Comment: No, Hibernation is S4, I want S3. Going in and out of S3 takes 5 seconds, versus a minute for S4.